# Should I be storing poke-api data locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a complete pokedex app using react-native/expo with all 900+ Pokémon.

I've tried what seems like countless ways of fetching the data from the API, but it's really slow.

Not sure if it's my code or the sheer amount of data:

```
export const getAllPokemon = async (offset: number) => {

  const data = await fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=${offset}`
  );
  const json = await data.json();

  const pokemonURLS: PokemonURLS[] = json.results;

  const monData: PokemonType[] = await Promise.all(
    pokemonURLS.map(async (p, index: number) => {
      const response = await fetch(p.url);
      const data: PokemonDetails = await response.json();
      const speciesResponse = await fetch(data.species.url);
      const speciesData: SpeciesInfo = await speciesResponse.json();

      return {
        name: data.name,
        id: data.id,
        image: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/${data.id}.png`,
        description: speciesData.flavor_text_entries,
        varieties: speciesData.varieties,
        color: speciesData.color.name,
        types: data.types,
        abilities: data.abilities,
      };
    })
  );
```

Then I'm using it with a useEffect that increases offset by 10 each time and concats the arrays, until offset > 900.

However like I said, it's really slow.

Should I be saving this data locally to speed things up a little?

And how would I go about it? Should I use local storage or save an actual file somewhere in my project folder with the data?

Comment: Slow as in 20 seconds or 1 hour?

Comment: Since it's a mobile app, I would suggest you to show a loading indicator the first time the user launches the application, it might take some time to query a large set of the Pokémons. You'll memoize this response (cache) it somewhere far away from where the state changes, you can keep them inside the local storage if you'd like, then you can use that chached data to show the pokemons you like

Comment: I mean when testing the app through expo-go on WiFi it takes maybe 3 minutes. But when I built the APK and tried to load it with 4g it was taking up to 6 minutes.

Comment: I'll try storing it with local storage and see how it goes!

Comment: I think you're going to have a data transfer problem on any slow network, if the one I looked up is representative.  The main API said there were 1154 entries, and the one I tried was 188 KB.  That's going to require over 200 MB of transfer, even if you're storing much less.  Do you have a back-end where you could look this up and store your reduced set weekly/daily/hourly?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest performance issue I can see is the multiple fetches you perform as you loop though each pokemon.

I'm guessing that the data returned by the two nested fetches (response and speciesResponse) is reference data and are potentially the same for multiple pokemon. If this is the case, and you can't change the api, then two options pop to mind:

Load the reference data only when needed ie. when a user clicks on a pokemon to view details.

**or**

Get **ALL** the reference data before the pokemon data and either combine it with your pokemon fetch results or store it locally and reference it as needed. The first way can be achieved using local state - just keep it long enough to merge the relevant data with the pokemon data. The second will need application state like redux, context (useContext hook) or browser storage (see localStorage or indexeddb).

Comment: Yeah I could change it so the speciesData only gets fetched on click. - Initially I needed it because it contains the color property which I was using for styling the background of each Pokémon entry. However I'm using another method now.

Comment: But yeah speciesData is unique for each mon. Just contains more info.

Comment: If its only a few thousand records I would still consider downloading all species' data and keeping it in local state for quick reference. You can limit the size by fetching only the most important columns.